# Modifying the appearance of an inherited control

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, radgridview

I have a proprietary component from Telerik called RadGridView. It's a simple GridView with some extended functionality. There's not much to say about it, it's just a control.
I'd love to add paging support to it, so I created this composite control:

[image]

There's not much to it, just a RadGridView with a Fill docking property, with a toolstrip bar above it with a Top docking property.

The problem with this approach, is that it doesn't match the interface of the RadGridView. I need to replace every occurrence of the RadGridView with this, and that could be very problematic.

I need to find a way to do the same thing by inheriting from RadGridView. It is an inheritable control, and all of its methods are virtual. What I don't know how to do, is how to modify its appearance so the toolstrip bar appears docked right above the RadGridView. I've read that I should modify the OnPaint event, but I'm confused as to where to go from there. The designer on Visual Studio doesn't allow me to modify its appearance either when inheriting from RadGridView.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way of doing this is:

```
class CustomButton : Button
{
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
    {
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.Width = 100;
        tb.Height = 20;
        tb.Top = this.Top - 20;
        tb.Left = this.Left;

        this.Parent.Controls.Add(tb);
        base.OnPaint(pevent);
    }
}
```

After compiling, you will see the control available in your tool box.
Of course, you can play around with the properties, but this is the basic. So, create a custom control that will represent the paging and add it this way.

Solution 2:
Create a composite control (like you did) and expose the RadGridView as a property of that control.

Answer (score 0):

There is already an example demonstrating paging here: [Gridview paging using CommandBar](http://www.telerik.com/support/pits.aspx#/details/Issue=14050)
and a sample demonstrating how to add elements to RadGridView here: [Add elements to RadGridView](http://admin.telerik.com/?Context=Support&Control=~/UserControls/Support/ThreadReply.ascx&ST=589548&SM=0)